# Has the killing of a cow been categorised as a mahapataka in any text or versions thereof?

Tags: scripture, dharma-shastras, sin, cows

In a particular text (not able to remember) there was a line which said that :
**A Brahmin, a woman and a cow must never be slain.**

This statement is in line with the [pancha mahapataka](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19613) among which, is the killing of a Brahmin and a sin equivalent to it, which is the [killing of a woman](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45424). However according to some Dharmashastras (Manu and Parasara go into some more details), **the killing of a cow is categorised as an Upapataka** something on level (may be slightly graver but it’s still categorised under Upapataka) with any other killing, which is surprising to note, considering the [holiness of the cow](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19670/is-the-concept-of-holy-cow-found-in-the-vedic-literature/19672#19672) and [prescription against its killing](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19213/do-the-vedas-order-killing-of-the-sinner-who-kills-a-cow) even in Vedic texts.

Besides the Vedic support against cow killing, in another text, it has been stated that **hearing vilification of God is equivalent to the sin of killing a cow**. I’m sure that vilifying or hearing thus about God should be one of the gravest of sins and not merely an Upapataka, therefore-

**Question:**
Is there any evidence from any of the scriptures to show that the killing of a cow is a Mahapataka, equivalent to the killing of a Brahmin or a woman?

The answer may not necessarily be from Dharmashastras although those are preferable opposed to a single line from Itihasa Purana. Additionally, it would be nice to have information on any pre-colonial versions or even quotes in Smriti compendium books in this regard (similar to [quotes](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6667/rules-for-wearing-yagyopavit-by-women-yes-it-is-possible/6668#6668) about women being allowed Upanayanam).

Incidentally if a reference to the vilification of God being a Mahapataka is found too, it would be a nice accompaniment.